# Implement Layering of screens on Android

Tags: android

I want to implement layering of screens when transitioning from one screen to another.

Requirement:

i> There is a screen with a button.

ii> When the user clicks on the button , the next screen is displayed in the following manner.

It should move up from down & place on top of the existing screen.
On iPhone , technically its known as implementing the **present model view controller**

I am aware of moving screens left & right , but is there already available API for implementing what I have mentioned.

Any inputs/sample code for implementing the same will be useful.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API to override the default transition animation between two Activities in 2.0 and higher: `overridePendingTransition()`.  It should be called just after `startActivity()` or `finish()` like so:

```
Intent intent = //New Intent to start your next Activity
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.custom, 0);
```

Where `R.anim.custom` is a custom animation you define in XML to slide up from the bottom.

Prior to Android 2.0, you would need to put both views in the same Activity and use something like a `ViewFlipper` to animate between the two views using the same custom animation.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well you should first set the view that you want don't want to see any long to be invisible. Do this with View.setVisibility(8) which is the value for Gone which "This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int)." Then you need to have a new view with the "next screen" set as a background. You can then transition that in using an animation. In your animation xml it will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

       <translate
        android:fromX="float"
        android:toX="float"
        android:fromY="float"
        android:toY="float" />
```

[Check out this doc to learn about animations.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) 
[Check this to lean about views in android.](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/index.html)